# How to add an APN when "Mobile networks" setting is disabled?

Tags: apn

I've got an unrooted Samsung Galaxy S5 from T-Mobile running Marshmallow (6.0.1), and am trying to add an APN so as to use the phone with FreedomPop. I've installed the FP SIM card and entered the unlock code. The next step is to add an APN for FP, but when I try to access the relevant settings (Settings→Connections→More networks→Mobile networks), "Mobile networks" is disabled (grey text, tapping has no effect). How can I enable the settings (the preferable route), or, failing that, add an APN in another way? (So far, the other methods I've seen require other steps (e.g. rooting the phone) which have their own roadblocks.)

"Mobile networks" remains disabled after switching back to the T-Mobile SIM card. The phone lists the ICCID for each card when inserted.

Comment: Does the phone recognize the Sim? Cuz I've had a time when my Sim wasn't activated and apn settings didn't work. But if it doesn't work with other Sim cards either, then i guess it's blocked by the carrier

Comment: Besides, if the card is not accepted by the device, the APN will be useless. Android choses "usable" APNs by the MCC and [MNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) detected from the carrier signal, so the "base signal" must be there to begin with.

Comment: The phone appears to recognize the SIM. At least, the SIM's ICCID is listed in device settings, and doesn't display any error messages regarding the SIM.